# Getting Video feed from ARDRONE using openCV in ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, ros, ar.drone

I would like to program a controller for the ARDRONE 2.0 in ROS using openCV. Can anyone help me with what library/code to use to get video feed from the drone to process in openCV and pass control commands to the drone from openCV using ROS.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first become familiar with ROS I would suggest following the basic tutorials to get you started.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

After that you can install ardrone_autonomy package which has everything you need to set up your AR-Drone with ROS. Including the AR-Drone camera drivers you need to use with OpenCv.

https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy

After that you can just write an Opencv function, implement it as a ROS node and have that node subscribe to the /ardrone/image_raw topic and publish control commands back to the AR-Drone

Comment: thanks for the reply, I went though the ROS tutorials and i can get video feed from the ARDrone now however im still stuck on the implementation of the passing controls to the drone.

Comment: You have to publish your control messages over the cmd_vel topic. The git for the ardrone_autonomy package is well documented it includes everything you need to know. https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy#sending-commands-to-ar-drone